# Need to merge many rows in one JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, merge

How to make from this:

```
 {"color":[{"id":"41","name":"red"}]}
 {"color":[{"id":"19","name":"blue"}]}
 ...
```

this thing by php and json_encode

```
 {"color":[{"id":"41","name":"red"},{"id":"19","name":"blue"},...]}
```

Data come from DB and I use folowing code:

```
 $json = array();
 $jsonRow= array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getResult)) {
    $jsonRow = array(
        $row['color'] => array(
            array(
                "id" => $row['id'],
                "name" => $row['name'],
            )
        )
    );
    array_push($json,$jsonRow);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$json = array();
$colors= array();

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getResult)) {

        array_push($colors,
            array(
                "id" => $row['id'],
                "name" => $row['name'],
            )
    );
    $json = array( "colors" => $colors);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $arr= array();
 $jsonRow= array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getResult)) {
    $jsonRow =  array(
                "id" => $row['id'],
                "name" => $row['name'],
            );
    $arr[]=$jsonRow;
 }
$json = json_encode(array('color'=>$arr));
echo $json;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
 $json = array();
 $jsonRow= array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getResult)) {
    $jsonRow[] = array(
       "id" => $row['id'],
       "name" => $row['name'],
    );
 }
 // color can be $row['color']
 // If its constant, I am not sure if its a good idea to keep in the loop.
 $json = array("color" => $jsonRow); 
 echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: wrong. that'll convert the array into a string. you DON'T do that with json. json can perfectly well handle nested arrays/objects.

Comment: You are right, this answer is according to output required by OP `{"color":[{"id":"41","name":"red"},{"id":"19","name":"blue"},...]}`. I doubt `json_encode()` as suggested by OP can bring such output, so...